# Kernel 4.8 UFW and SMB not working together

Tags: kernel, samba, firewall, ufw, smb

Good day, I recently encountered a strange error regarding samba shares. I set up the shared directories on multiple computers on my home network. I enabled ufw and added samba rule with 'ufw allow samba'. Since I have kaby lake processor in my laptop I updated to the 4.8 kernel series with 'sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge'. If I load the 4.8 kernel the ufw firewall blocks my connections to other samba shares on the network. If I disable the firewall I can connect to the other shares. Incoming connections are not blocked to this computer even with firewall on. Strangely everything works as it should if I boot with 4.4 kernel but it again broken when I try the newer kernel. There seems to be other people experiencing this strange behavior as well over the Lnux Mint community as well: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=235049

I just wanted to point this issue out in case the ubuntu developers are not aware of it and ask any advice how to fix this. The solution over the Mint forums are a bit to technical for me I'm afraid.

Comment: This sounds like a reproducible bug - so a good candidate for posting  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

You can always compare `iptables-save > before-4.4` to `iptables-save > after-4.8` to see if there was an impact to iptables or ufw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, the Arch wiki was updated with this specific problem in mind, they list it as a possible solution but it works on booth my Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon installations.

Type this in the terminal:

```
sudo iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns
```

Since any change to iptables is lost on reboot without a configuration file I installed the iptables-persistent package, this way the 'fix' will not be gone after a system restart. To install type this in the terminal, and save the current rules.

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
```

<sub>Source for solution: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#.22Browsing.22_network_fails_with_.22Failed_to_retrieve_share_list_from_server.22</sub>

Comment: Fixed it perfectly