# smbtree returns nothing if firewall active

Tags: samba, ufw

The systems are at different kernel levels
Two systems each running XUBUNTU 16.04. When ufw (firewall) is disable, both give a full list of shares, some of which are Ubuntu while others are Windows XP.  If the ufw firewall is enabled, one of the systems continues to give a list of shares, the other one does not.
- Both are current per the software updater
- The working one was brought to 16.04 two years ago (kernel is 4.4.0-133-generic)
- The failing one was recently installed from a downloaded DVD image (kernel is 4.15.0-32-generic) then configured using the working one as a reference for configurations etc.

ufw shows the following rules, which are identical except for order

3389                       ALLOW       192.168.1.64
3389                       ALLOW       192.168.1.65
3389                       ALLOW       192.168.1.66
3389                       ALLOW       192.168.1.67
3389                       ALLOW       192.168.1.68
23/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
23/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

A probably unrelated curious thing is that any time I enable the ufw (firewall), my remote (xrdp) session freezes but only on the system that returns nothing to smbtree with firewall enabled.

Comment: Are the application profiles (`/etc/ufw/applications.d/samba`) identical, at least in terms of ports? BTW I assume that's `samba` with a lower-case `s` - unless you created your own application profile in place of the one provided by the `samba` package?

Comment: You might want to look here for a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875845/kernel-4-8-ufw-and-smb-not-working-together