# How can I setup Ufw to be able to connect to a windows network shared folder using the hostname of the machine?

Tags: samba, ufw, shared-folders

How can I setup Ufw to be able to connect to a windows network shared folder using the hostname of the machine?

Connecting to the machine by IP does work.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

### Tried so far:

#### Opened ports as of [Samba AD DC Port Usage](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_Port_Usage) page

```
ports=53/tcp|53/udp|123/udp|135/tcp|137/udp|138/udp|139/udp|389/tcp|389/udp|445/tcp|636/tcp|636/tcp|3268/tcp|3269/tcp|49152:65535/tcp
```

Comment: You are going to get yelled at for a duplicate question. Questions: (1) What version of Ubuntu are you using? (2) By any chance does the problem go away when you access the Win8 machine by its ip address rather than by name?

Comment: Good points, please see my edit.

Comment: The problem is the way ufw handles the response from the server when queried by the Linux client when NetBIOS is used which is why it works when you access it by ip address. Please see this:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148774/cant-ping-windows-hostname?noredirect=1&lq=1 OR THIS: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875845/kernel-4-8-ufw-and-smb-not-working-together

Comment: You should write an answer out of that, especially since none of the answers explains why this is needed (this info is in the blog post that is linked in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148774/cant-ping-windows-hostname?noredirect=1&lq=1 though :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!